# javascript looping items in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, markup

My mind is drawing a blank right now..  I have an array of months:

```
var month_array = new Array();

month_array[0] = "January";
month_array[1] = "February";
month_array[2] = "March";
month_array[3] = "April";
month_array[4] = "May";
month_array[5] = "June";
month_array[6] = "July";
month_array[7] = "August";
month_array[8] = "September";
month_array[9] = "October";
month_array[10] = "November";
month_array[11] = "December";
```

I'm trying to output markup as:

```
<ul>
  <li>  January & Feburary </li>
  <li>  March & April </li>
etc.
</ul>
```

Looping thru the array isn't a problem but what I cannot figure out right now is an elegant way to loop thru every 2 items in the array..

I'm able to do it by using the below to format the array the way I need it to but I think this isn't a good direction as its redundant.

```
var months =  month_array.map(function(elem,i,arr){
                return [elem, (i+1<arr.length) ? arr[i+1] : null];
            }).filter(function(elem,i){
                return (i%2);
            });
```

Anyone know of the best way to group by 2 items in an array?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < month_array.length; i += 2) { ... }`

Comment: vanilla `for` loop, `i+=2` ?

Comment: You seem to be over complicating it by trying to use `.map` rather than just a regular old `for` loop. And not only is your attempt overly complicated, it doesn't actually work. The first item is `[Feburary],[March]`

Comment: only month_array[++i]; inisde a regular for is needed!

Comment: @Csdtesting: That sounds absolutely horrible in terms of readability and maintainability. Don't mess with the loop variable inside the loop! What's wrong with `i+=2` as Regent and Alex both suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes `.for loop` is quite enough! 
Why don't you try this one inside for loop `month_array[++i];` Or simply and better `i += 2` at the `.for` statement:

**Demo 1:**

```js
var month_array = new Array();
var cList = $('ul.mylist')
month_array[0] = "January";
month_array[1] = "February";
month_array[2] = "March";
month_array[3] = "April";
month_array[4] = "May";
month_array[5] = "June";
month_array[6] = "July";
month_array[7] = "August";
month_array[8] = "September";
month_array[9] = "October";
month_array[10] = "November";
month_array[11] = "December";

for (var i = 0, l = month_array.length; i < l; i+=2) {
var final = month_array[i] + " & " + month_array[i + 1]; 
var li = $('<li/>').html(final).appendTo(cList);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mylist">
</ul>
```

**Demo 2 - Choose demo 1 is better!:**

```js
var month_array = new Array();
var cList = $('ul.mylist')
month_array[0] = "January";
month_array[1] = "February";
month_array[2] = "March";
month_array[3] = "April";
month_array[4] = "May";
month_array[5] = "June";
month_array[6] = "July";
month_array[7] = "August";
month_array[8] = "September";
month_array[9] = "October";
month_array[10] = "November";
month_array[11] = "December";

for (var i = 0, l = month_array.length; i < l; i++) {
  var final = month_array[i] + " & " + month_array[++i];
  var li = $('<li/>').html(final).appendTo(cList);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mylist">
</ul>
```

Comment: Modifying the control variable in the loop will make some people angry, `i += 2` makes everything clear.

Comment: I did that to understand which item is showing for him.I knew that.but anyway it is a strange question. Maybe i did wrong to answer that anyway

Comment: You could change to +=2 ;)

Comment: Awesome..  I did change to +=2 and i < month_array.length

Comment: So, finally, we end up with what we have started 50 minutes ago :) +1 for first demo.

Comment: I was quite close to quit...that strange question.I hope this help someone in the future though :)

Answer (score 1):

While I think this is way easier to just use a regular `for` loop as @Regent suggested in the comments, you could do this with an `array.reduce` like this:

```
var months = month_array.reduce(function (pre, curr, idx, arr) {
    if (!(idx % 2)) {
        pre.push([curr, arr[idx + 1]]);
    }
    return pre;
}, []);

console.log(months);
```

This will give you an array containing six arrays each containing two months, starting with `["January","February"]`

**Note:** in the case of grouping an array with an odd number of items, the last item in your reduced array will be `[lastItemInSourceArray, undefined]`. You can add logic to handle that case if necessary depending on what you actually need to do. In the case of `12` months, it's obviously not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated. Preserves original array.

Try

v3

```
var ul = $("<ul>");
var month_array = ["January", "February", "March", "April"
                  , "May", "June", "July", "August"
                  , "September", "October", "November", "December"];

(function arr(m, n) {
    if (ul.children("li").size() < m.length / 2) {
        ul.append("<li>" 
                  + m.slice(n, n + 2).join(" & ") 
                  + "</li>");
                  n = n + 2;
        arr(m, n)
    } else {
        $("body").append(ul);
        console.log(month_array)
    }
}(month_array, 0));
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/orrje6qo/4/

Comment: Well, it works, but what is the point to overcomplicate the task and to destroy array?

Answer (score 0):

**The answer u r looking for..!!**

```
<body>
  <div class="listDiv">
    <ul></ul> 
  </div>
</body>



var month_array = [];
month_array[0] = "January";
month_array[1] = "February";
month_array[2] = "March";
month_array[3] = "April";
month_array[4] = "May";
month_array[5] = "June";
month_array[6] = "July";
month_array[7] = "August";
month_array[8] = "September";
month_array[9] = "October";
month_array[10] = "November";
month_array[11] = "December";
var array=[];
for(var i=1; i<month_array.length; ++i) {
  array[i] = '<li>' + month_array[i-1] + ' & ' +month_array[i] + '</li>';
}

$('.listDiv ul').append(array);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/raeegzrb/

**checkout the output markup as well.**